# Multidimensional array retriving (OOP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have two classes (Database for queries over database) and News for manipulating articles. On index.php (could be any other page) i call News class, which calls Database class. Everything goes ok, until i have to display result on index.php.

Let's say, i save result in $news in News class.
How should i retrieve that array in index.php (like return $this->news or something else??). And how to display?

Could someone help.

Comment: post some code, otherwise it's very hard to be of any use to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On index.php (could be any other page) i call News class, which calls Database class.

You don't "call classes". You call methods of classes.

> Let's say, i save result in $news in News class.

I suppose you mean you have a *field* (also *property* in PHP) names `news`, as in:

```
class News {
    private $news;
    /* ... */
}
```

> How should i retrieve that array in index.php (like return $this->news or something else??)

You could add a method in `News` that returned this array:

```
class News {
    private $news;
    function retrieveNews() {
        /* query the DB and store the result in $this->news */
    }
    function getData() { return $this->news; }
}
```

Or you could make it public and access it directly through `$newsObject->news` (not recommended).

> And how to display?

That depends on the structure of the data and how you want to display it.

Comment: applause :D i couldnt do anything with that question :D

Comment: thanks for reply, 
first, sorry for bad terminology, im not native English speaker, so words dont come easy:)
My problem is actually how to display that content (returned data), just where you stopped in your reply.
Assuming that database query was: "select news_id, title, body, date where author_id='aid'";
I save result in $this->news and return to index.php

And now i tried to use foreach loop, and some other functions but with no success. One of my tries:
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    foreach($news[$i] as $a=>$b){
        echo $b;
   }
}

The structure of the display itself is another issue.

Comment: @php Again, that depends on the structure of the data. Do a `var_dump($news)` to see it.

Comment: All my attempts to display data in index.php get error: "Cannot use object of type News as array in..."

Comment: @php Well that's because you're using a News object as in `$newsObject[$index]` and `$newsObject` is neither an array not an object that implements ArrayAccess.

Comment: @artefacto thanks, i will try to adjust data in some News method before it is ready for displaying. I can already see its gonna be a long day:)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Database{               // database.php
function news($user_id){ 
$q="select all from news where author id='$id'"; 
$result=$db->query($q); 
for($i=0; $i<$r->num_rows; $i++){   
    $arr[]=$result->fetch_array;  
} 
return $arr; }}

class News{              //  news.php
function get_news($user_id){
$news=$db->news($user_id);
return $news;
}}

index.php  // problem how to display
$post=new News;
$post->get_news($user_id);
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
    foreach($post[$i] as $k=>$v){
       echo $v;         //get error: "Cannot use object of type News as array in ..."
}}
```